# Align center to imagebutton on same line android

Tags: android

I have a layout with 3 `ImageButtons` one to the right of the other as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main3con"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="cards"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textx"
        android:src="@drawable/random_40x40" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/add_40x40" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:src="@drawable/reset_40x40" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listVieww"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="New Text" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see, I aligned the `TextView` "@+id/textx" to the center using `android:gravity="center"` and I want to align the `ImageButtons` to the center too, I tried surrounding it with `LinearLayout` and such things but I don't know how to do it. I want to align them in the same line, meaning like the three first buttons [here](http://gcmuganda.faculty.noctrl.edu/classes/Fall14/502/Homework1/Images/Figure2.PNG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `horizontal` linear layout and assign weights to `ImageButtons` like so:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="40dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/random_40x40"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_40x40"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/reset_40x40"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```